# How to run a query every 2 minutes in mule using quartz

Tags: java, mule, mule-flow

I want to execute my query every 2 minutes, but I get following error.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. No serializer found for class org.mule.transport.NullPayload and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException)
  org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer:52 (null)
2. No serializer found for class org.mule.transport.NullPayload and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  org.mule.module.json.transformers.ObjectToJson:107 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.mule.transport.NullPayload and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:25)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:610)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

My flow is as below.

```
 <flow name="testdbFlow1" doc:name="testdbFlow1">
      
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz" jobName="CronJobSchedule" repeatInterval="0" cronExpression="0 0/2 * ? * MON-FRI" repeatCount="1">                   
    <quartz:event-generator-job/>
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint queryKey="select_qry" queryTimeout="-1"  connector-ref="Database" doc:name="Database"/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/> 

</flow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following by adding quartz:payload :-

```
<flow name="testdbFlow1" doc:name="testdbFlow1">
<quartz:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz" jobName="CronJobSchedule" repeatInterval="0" cronExpression="0 0/2 * ? * MON-FRI" repeatCount="1">                   
        <quartz:event-generator-job>
<quartz:payload>quartzSchedular started</quartz:payload>
</quartz:event-generator-job>
        </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
        <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint queryKey="select_qry" queryTimeout="-1"  connector-ref="Database" doc:name="Database"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/> 

    </flow>
```

**Update :-**
use logger  after **json:object-to-json-transformer** like the following :-

```
<logger message="#[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

and remove echo component ...

and make **exchange-pattern="request-response"** in JDBC component like the following :-

```
<jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint queryKey="select_qry" queryTimeout="-1"  connector-ref="Database" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="Database"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply here as echo "quartzSchedulat started" print in console..but i want to print all my database record in my console..

Comment: one more question i want to check in database if i have more than 1 record than after fire my delete query.Is it possible using expression?? How can I do this ???

Comment: If you want to check if you have more than 1 record than you need to use SQL query for that .. For example .. if you want to check if you have more than 1 record in DB for same id .. then use a Java class and then write a SQL query some what like int countNo=SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE user_id =Your ID here .... Now if your variable countNo is equal or greater than 1 then record exists more than 1 .. you need to add a Java class after this and call the JDBC query like SQL count from there